# Defining zsh functions in a loop reassigns pre

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to make a tool that defines functions in zsh based off of some named directories. Currently I have this:

```
while read line; do
    p=( `echo $line | egrep -o -e "[^ ]+"` )
    alias go${p[1]}="cd ${p[2]}"
    put${p[1]}()
    {
        mv $1 ${p[2]}
    }
done < "$HOME/.pro_targets"
```

which works for the aliases, but typing put[target] on the commandline gives me

`mv: cannot mv 'wol.sh' to '$HOME/work/tagfs/fuse-tutorial/src': No such file or directory`

Which refers to the last value of `$p`. I think I need the function to close around the variable `${p[2]}` and substitute based on the environment it had when it was defined so it can vary with each definition.

Comment: $HOME is not getting expanded, and it is looking for a path literally named '$HOME/work/...'

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a directory literally named '$HOME' in the current working directory, that doesn't sound like a real directory.

What has happened is that environment substitution (i.e. translating $HOME-> /home/username) hasn't happened on the contents of the file.

Try:

```
envsubst < "$HOME/.pro_targets" | \
  while read line; do
      p=( `echo $line | egrep -o -e "[^ ]+"` )
      alias go${p[1]}="cd ${p[2]}"
      put${p[1]}()
      {
          mv $1 ${p[2]}
      }
  done
```

If you only want $HOME to work, try

```
env -i HOME="$HOME" envsubst < "$HOME/.pro_targets" | ...
```